# How can I put the rest of the data under some PHP

Tags: php

my problem is I try to show all the data from the database using PHP and put it in a table and it works for me but the problem all the data it become in one line like the photo
[image]

and i want to be like this

[image]

this my code

```html
<h1>Delete The Recode</h1>
<div class='tablee'>
  <table name="table" style="width:100%" method="post">
    <tr>
      <th>author</th>
      <th>title</th>
      <th>type</th>
      <th>year</th>
      <th>isbn</th>
    </tr>
    <tr></tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

```php
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "saleh";
$password = "saleh";
$dbname = "publications";
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
   die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM classics";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while ($row =$result->fetch_assoc()) {
   echo "<td>" . $row['author'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['type'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['year'] . "</td>";
   echo "<td>" . $row['isbn'] . "</td>";
}

$conn->close();
?>
```

Comment: The `<tr>` and `</tr>` tags should be inside the `foreach` loop.

Comment: Whenever your layout is not what you expect, it's best to first have a look at the page source - right click and choose `View page source` and see what was generated (note: this is *not* the same as inspecting HTML in your developer toolbar, because that shows output after the browser tried to fix whatever jumbled markup it ran across). You'd notice at that point that you only have one row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just put the `<tr>` in the wrong place, so you need to put it in `while` and remove the `<tr>` that are before your php script 
So your final code will be like this :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>From</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="indexStyle.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Delete The Recode</h1>
        <div class = 'tablee' >
            <table name = "table" style="width:100%" method="post">
                <tr>
                    <th>author</th>
                    <th>title</th> 
                    <th>type</th>
                    <th>year</th>
                    <th>isbn</th>
                </tr>
                <?php
                    $servername = "localhost";
                    $username = "saleh";
                    $password = "saleh";
                    $dbname = "publications";
                    $conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
                    if ($conn->connect_error) {
                        die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
                    }
                    $sql = "SELECT * FROM classics";
                    $result = $conn->query($sql);

                    while($row =$result->fetch_assoc()){
                        echo "<tr>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['author'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['type'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['year'] . "</td>";
                        echo "<td>" . $row['isbn'] . "</td>";
                        echo "</tr>";
                    }
                    $conn->close();
                ?>
            </table>
        </div> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `<tr>` inside while loop as below:

```
while($row =$result->fetch_assoc()){
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['author'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['title'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['type'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['year'] . "</td>";
      echo "<td>" . $row['isbn'] . "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
      
      

    }
```